# Prove that a ring R having the property that every ﬁnitely generated R-module is free is either a ﬁeld or the zero ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, proof-explanation, free-modules

https://wj32.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/advanced-linear-algebra.pdf

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/about-r-module.313248/

http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic256346.files/Set%207.pdf

http://121.192.180.130:901/media/5225/homework13.pdf

http://121.192.180.130:901/media/5252/2015-01-07abstract%20algebra32.pdf

These are proofs that I can find so far. But among all of them, I cannot understand a point that:

I think all of these proofs only shows that if **$R/I$** is a free module over R, than R must be either a field or the zero ring.

But I cannot see how does it imply the fact that: If **every** finitely generated R-module is free, then R must be either a field or the zero ring.

Could someone tell me how to show that? Thank so much!

Comment: Is $R$ any ring or any commutative ring?

Comment: R is any commutative ring.

Comment: In fact, the property can be restated as follows: If every **cyclic** R-module is free, then R must be either a field or the zero ring.

Comment: The link to `isites.harvard.edu` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $I \subseteq R$ be an ideal. Then $R/I$ is an $R$-module. Moreover, it is generated by the element $\overline{1} \in R/I$. So $R/I$ is a finitely-generated $R$-module.

Then by assumption $R/I$ is free. Assume for contradiction that $I$ is not equal to $0$ or $R$. First, since $R/I \neq 0$, $R/I$ is not spanned by the empty set. So it must have a basis $\{\overline{r_1}, \ldots \overline{r_k}\}$ which is nonempty. But since $I \neq 0$, we can choose some $i \in I\setminus \{0\}$, and then $i\cdot \overline{r_1} = 0$. Thus, the "basis" is actually linearly dependent.

This is a contradiction, and thus we conclude that $I$ must have been $0$ or $R$, i.e. $0$ and $R$ are the only ideals of $R$. This implies that $R$ is either the zero ring or a field.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't even know about the concept of torsion-free... Could you just tell me why "if R/I is a free module over R, than R must be either a field or the zero ring" implies "If every finitely generated R-module is free, than R must be either a field or the zero ring"?

Comment: @Y.X. An $R$-module $M$ is torsion-free if for every $r \in R$ and every $m \in M$, then $rm = 0$ iff $r=0$ or $m=0$.

Comment: @Y.X. Suppose that every finitely generated $R$-module is free. Then in particular, the $R$-modules $R/I$ are all free, since they are finitely generated as I showed above. Thus, my proof goes through that $R$ must be $0$ or a field.

Comment: But are the R/I modules exhaust all the modules over R? Or all the R-modules are isomorphic to some R/I?

Comment: Over a ring with zero divisors, a free module need not be torsion free.

Comment: @Y.X. No, the modules $R/I$ do not exhaust all finitely-generated $R$-modules. But that doesn't matter at all! We are supposing that all finitely generated $R$-modules are free, so in particular, this is true of all of the modules $R/I$.

Comment: @ Oh I see I made a mistake about logic... But now, could you please explain why we can use the fact that R/I is torsion free? As Noah said, I think we cannot assume that the R has no zero divisors...

Comment: @AlexG. The proof is very nearly correct but not for the reason I mentioned in my comment above. I suggest the following edit: you are trying to show that either $I=0$ or $I=R$. Assume $I \neq 0$. Then there is nonzero $a \in I$, and multiplication by $a$ kills the module $R/I$. While a free module can have "torsion" (do people even define torsion for non domains??), free modules cannot be killed by multiplication by a nonzero element, one sees this from e.g. the definition of a basis.

Comment: @NoahOlander I just corrected the proof. Thanks for the input. It no longer assumes that $R$ is a domain.

Comment: @Y.X. The proof has been generalized to no longer assume that free $R$-modules are torsion-free, which is not true in general as Noah pointed out.

Comment: AlexG. Your definition of "torsion-free is not quite right. @NoahOlander "*do people even define torsion for non domains?*" Yes, they do: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion-free_module