# Prove that if a nonzero commutative ring R with identity has the property that every finitely generated R-module is free then R is a field.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

[Prove that a ring R having the property that every ﬁnitely generated R-module is free is either a ﬁeld or the zero ring.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970479/prove-that-a-ring-r-having-the-property-that-every-%EF%AC%81nitely-generated-r-module-is)

This question has been asked before at the link above, but I am trying to prove it in a somewhat different vein, largely because I spent a while on it before looking for alternative answers and can't get past a certain point.  Maybe some of my intermediate steps are incorrect.

Let $v\in R$, $v\neq0$.  Consider the cyclic $R$-module $\langle\langle v \rangle\rangle = \{rv\mid\ v\in R\}$.  This is a finitely generated $R$-module and so has a basis by assumption, specifically $\{v\}$.  Then $\{v\}$ is linearly independent, and so for any $r\in R$, $rv=0$ implies that $r=0$.  Since $v$ is an arbitrary non-zero element in $R$, we can apply the same method to any other non-zero element $u$ of $R$ and conclude that for any nonzero $u \in R$, $ru=0$ implies $r = 0$.  So $R$ has no zero divisors and is thus an Integral Domain.

First of all, are the assertions I have made thus far correct?  If not, please let me know.  If this is correct to this point, is there a way to extend this to demonstrate the existence of multiplicative inverses in $R$ and thus to show that $R$ is a field in a way that does not rely on the $R/I$ approach used in the link above?

Comment: Nothing wrong so far, but you may want to use $r.(s.v)=v$ is also going to have a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I can't see how to establish the above relationship though.  My guess is that if I could establish that for arbitrary nonzero $s$ there exists $r$ such that $r.(s.v)=v$, then this implies $(r.s-1).v=0$, and so $r.s=1$ since there are no zero divisors.  Then $s$ has inverse $r$.  First, if you could elaborate a little bit more on your comment, I would really appreciate it.  Second, are the statements I have just made a valid approach, provided I can establish $r.(s.v)=v$?

Comment: Yes, this is how you proceed.

Comment: OK.  I still am having problems with establishing that $r.(s.v)=v$.  My initial thought was to use a result from a previous theorem that if $R$ is an integral domain and $M$ is an $R-module$ with a subset $S$ of linearly independent vectors, then if I multiply each element in $S$ by a non-zero element $s$ in $R$, the set $sS$ will be linearly independent over $R$ as well, but no dice.  Are you saying that, given the fact that $R$ is an integral domain and the assumptions of the problem as stated, I should be able to demonstrate that $v$ is contained in the submodule $<<sv>>$ for nonzero $s$?

Comment: I should add, this is not specifically a homework problem.  I'm taking a grad course on Linear Algebra using Roman, but this problem was not assigned.  Not trying to get you to do my homework, just want to understand and find an alternate solution.

Comment: If $v\notin R.(s.v)$, then $R.(s.v)$ is a proper submodule of $V$, contrary to the assumption that $V$ is irreducible.

Comment: Line 2: can you explain why $\{v\}$ is a basis for $Rv$?

Comment: @Delong  $V$ is irreducible and $R.v$ is a sub module.

Comment: @DavidHill why is $Rv$ irreducible? Sorry. I'm not familiar with irreducible modules.

Comment: @Delong Actually, that's a good observation.  I made the assertion that {v} was a basis for $V$, but I suppose I can only conclude that, given the assumption that every finitely generated $R-module$ has a basis, the basis is of the form {$sv$} for some $s$ in $R$.  This obviously makes it easy to see that $v=r.(s.v)$ for some $r$ in $R$.  Unfortunately, I used the assertion that {v} was a basis for $V$ to show that $R$ was an Integral Domain, but now I can't make the assumption that $R$ has no zero divisors, so that $(r.s-1).v=0$ does not imply that r.s=1, and $r$ is a mult. inv. of $s$.